# Get mapping expression with Mapster

Tags: c#, mapster

Is it possible to get just the mapping expression, i.e., an object of type `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TSource, TTarget>>`? I would like to manually pass it to a Select-like function accepting an expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cs
Mapster.TypeAdapterConfig.GlobalSettings.Default.Config.CreateMapExpression(
  new Mapster.Models.TypeTuple(typeof(TSource), typeof(TTarget)), 
  Mapster.MapType.Projection);
```

Or if you are not using the global config, use your TypeAdapterConfig.
Change the MapType to best match what you are trying to do.